# generate element using ng-repeat but only show if condition met

Tags: angularjs

I want to generate element using `ng-repeat` but only want to show if some $scope.activeMod is equal to item's value, here how I am trying but not working. In activeMod value is mod1 but its showing all list items.
html code

```
<li ng-show="{activeMod == item.menu-mod}" ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-if="item.title != 'Home'">
    <a ng-href="{{item.href}}" class="{{item.className}}">{{item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

here is the menu json

```
{
    "title": "System",
    "menu-mod": "mod1",
    "className": "system-icon",
},
{
    "title": "Settings",
    "menu-mod": "mod2",
    "className": "settings-icon",
},
{
    "title": "Configs",
    "menu-mod": "mod3",
    "className": "config-icon",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-show="activeMod == item['menu-mod']" ng-if="item.title != 'Home'">
    <a ng-href="{{item.href}}" class="{{item.className}}">{{item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

Hope that `activeMod` is declared in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter in the ng-repeat declaration.

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu | filter: filterFunction" [...] etc.
```

and in the controller:

```
    $scope.filterFunction = function(item){

      if(item.menu-mod === $scope.activeMod) {return true;}
      return false;

    }
```

For more info in filters:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter#parameters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter#parameters)